# CSS - Table caption to apply to each tbody

Tags: html, css

**Note, this question has basically been overhauled from a previous version so as to be more precise. Thus some of the answers below do not completely the restructed question.*

I have two sets of data which I need to display tabulated. As both sets of data need to have the column widths (but still be dynamic), I am using two `<tbody>`'s.

I am trying to set a heading for each of the tabulated data, in a way that the heading takes up the width of the entire **`<tbody>`**.

I have tried using `table-caption`, but it does not apply to the `tbody`, but the `table` itself. Meaning all captions look to go to the top of the table, regardless of where they are in the html.

To demonstrate what I am running into, see the following snippet:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
tbody:before {
  display: table-caption;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #303030;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
#tbody1:before {
  content: 'tbody1';
}
#tbody2:before {
  content: 'tbody2';
}
th,
td {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
caption {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody1">
    <caption>Caption1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>bob</th>
      <th>dob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="tbody2">
    <caption>Caption2</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>dob</th>
      <th>bob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My current attempt is to use `:before`. But as you can see, the `:before` does not take up the entire width of the `tbody`. Even with `width: 100%` it does not work.

Another way I realized it could be done is to have another row for each `tbody`, and set `colspan` to equal the amount of columns for that table. Like this:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
caption {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody1">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Title1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>bob</th>
      <th>dob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="tbody2">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Title2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>dob</th>
      <th>bob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the only problem there is that it does not become dynamic and requires you to know how many columns there will be ahead of time. Normally this would not be a problem but I am looking for a more dynamic solution in my case.

> My question is: *How does one add a `caption` to a **`tbody`** (not the `table`) in a way so that each caption relates to the applicable `tbody` and **not the table***

Comment: if you switch table-caption to block, it takes up the entire row

Comment: @Keith thank you. but doing so makes the first column a lot larger

Comment: Is there particular a reason you're trying to make the `table:before` pseudo-element act like a table caption instead of using a `caption` element? Replacing your pseudo-elements with `caption` elements looks like it has the intended behaviour.

Comment: @SeanLeBlanc thank you. however it seems that there can only be one caption... so that does not fully work

Comment: Keep in mind that by design the `caption` tag applies to the `table` and is always the first descendant of the table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption

Comment: @JonP tku, I am tracking with that. I am trying to get a `caption` for each `tbody` (or some other way of having a title for each `tbody`). I have not found it yet, thus my OP

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the width to 100vw. This sets the width to 100% of the viewport width. For a more in-depth explanation of viewport width, see [this article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Relative_length_units)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#tbody1:before, #tbody2:before {
  display: table-caption;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #303030;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
}
#tbody1:before {
  content: 'tbody1';
}
#tbody2:before {
  content: 'tbody2';
}
th, td {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody1">
    <tr>
      <th>bob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="tbody2">
    <tr>
      <th>dob</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, but this only works if there is one column. Do you know how this would work if there were two columns?

Comment: It’s old, but it may help some searchers: to stretch a table cell (no matter if `th` or `td`) add an attribute `colspan` with a numeric value expressing the number of columns it should stretch over. Eg. to stretch a cell over 3 columns just add this:

` <td colspan="3">`